# Yup: How to validate two dates which are dependent on each other?

Tags: formik, yup

I am using `Formik` and `yup` for its validation.
I have the following requirements for validation of two fields `started` and `ended`

1. `started` must be a valid date.
2. `started` must be a past date.
3. `ended` can be null, means it is not required.
4. `ended` must not be null and must be a valid date if the `started`
   has a valid date value.

This is my validation schema:

```
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
    started: yup.date().max(new Date(), "Future date not allowed").typeError("Invalid Started date"),
    ended: yup.date().default(null).when("started", {
        is: yup.date().isValid(),
        then: yup.date().min(yup.ref("started"), "Ended date must be later than Start date"),
        otherwise: yup.date().nullable()
    }).typeError("Invalid Ended date")
})}
```

1,2,3 are working, but the 4th validation is not working.
I also tried changing it to `is: started => started !==null`, this is completely wrong because I `console.log(started)` and that printed me `Invalid date`.
I even tried `is: true` that also didn't work.

What would be the correct way of validating this requirement?

Answer (score 13):

Got this solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60277510.

But basically this will check that started exists and then check if end time is later:

```
 ended: yup.date().default(null)
                .when("started",
                    (started, yup) => started && yup.min(started, "End time cannot be before start time"))
```