# Yup date validation + 1 day

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I have a form using formik / yup, and I'm validating dates against other dates in the form. I have a field for `expirationDate` that I want to be at a minimum *the day after* `enteredDate`, the day the form was entered.

I currently have this, which works but validates against the `enteredDate`-- the problem is that if you set 06/21/21 as the entered date, it accepts 06/21/21 as the expiration date-- I need it to set 06/22/21 as the minimum date, or `enteredDate + 1 day`.

```
yup.date('Expiration Date')
    .nullable()
    .min(yup.ref('enteredDate'),
        ({ min }) => `Expiration Date needs to be after Entered Date`
    )
```

I've tried many variations of

```
yup.date('Expiration Date')
    .nullable()
    .min(yup.ref('enteredDate') ? daysjs(yup.ref('enteredDate').add(1, 'day') : null,
        ({ min }) => `Expiration Date needs to be after Entered Date`
    )
```

but the `yup.ref` doesn't seem to return a date object, since the error is `TypeError: The value of field could not be cast to a value that satisfies the schema type: "date".`

How can I tell yup to use the next day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.when` method to connect one field to another. [Docs.](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema)

This should work as expected:

```js
const schema = object({
  enteredDate: date().required(),
  expirationDate: date().when("enteredDate", (enteredDate, schema) => {
    if (enteredDate) {
      // This can be calculated in many ways. Just be sure that its type is `Date` object
      const dayAfter = new Date(enteredDate.getTime() + 86400000);

      return schema.min(dayAfter);
    }

    return schema;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this schema. Please make a note I have used moment. In .test you will have access for both the values (enteredDate and expirationDate). You can write your comparison logic by using dayjs.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    expirationDate: Yup.date()
      .required("Please input Expiry Date")
      .nullable()
      .test(
        "",
        "exp date should be greater than Entered Date + 1",
        (val, props) => {
          const expiryDate = moment(val);
          const enteredDate = moment(props.parent.enteredDate);
          const tmpExpiryDate = moment(enteredDate).add(1, "days");

          if (!tmpExpiryDate.isAfter(expiryDate)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      ),
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this snippet

```js
let today = new Date();
let tomorrow = new Date(new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate() + 1));

console.log("today: ", today);
console.log("tomorrow: ", tomorrow);
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, but the question isn't how to add dates, it was how to do date addition in a yup validation using a yup ref.