# How to implement interdependent formik fields

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I had a need to collect Start- and End Dates from users, with the requirement that they must be exactly 1 year apart. eg. if Start Date was picked as July 1st, then End Date was automatically calculated to be June 30th; if End Date was picked as September 23, then Start Date was automatically set as September 24. Year was not a factor here.

I was new to formik and after completed an online tutorial, I came up with the following prototype: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interdependent-formik-fields-q8xd1z?file=/src/CustomForm.tsx)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import CustomDatePicker from "./CustomDatePicker";

const CustomForm = () => {
  const [startAt, setStartAt] = useState("");
  const [endAt, setEndAt] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ startAt, endAt });
  }, [startAt, endAt]);

  const initialValues = {
    fieldStart: new Date('07-01') || null,
    fieldEnd: new Date('06-30') || null
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    fieldStart: Yup.date().required("Required").nullable(),
    fieldEnd: Yup.date().required("Required").nullable()
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log("submitted Form data", values);
  };

  const processFieldStart = (v) => {
    if (v) {
      setStartAt(v.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').substring(0, 5));

      var end = new Date(v.getTime());
      end.setDate(end.getDate() - 1);
      setEndAt(end.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').substring(0, 5));
    }
    return false;
  };

  const processFieldEnd = (v) => {
    if (v) {
      setEndAt(v.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').substring(0, 5));

      var start = new Date(v.getTime());
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      setStartAt(start.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').substring(0, 5));
    }
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      {(formik) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="fieldStart">Cycle Start </label>
              <Field name="fieldStart" validate={processFieldStart}>
                {({ form, field }) => {
                  const { setFieldValue } = form;
                  return (
                    <CustomDatePicker
                      format="dd/MM"
                      id="fieldStart"
                      name="fieldStart"
                      {...field}
                      onChange={(val) => setFieldValue("fieldStart", val)}
                    />
                  );
                }}
              </Field>
              <ErrorMessage name="fieldStart" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="fieldEnd"> Cycle End </label>
              <Field name="fieldEnd" validate={processFieldEnd}>
                {({ form, field }) => {
                  const { setFieldValue } = form;
                  return (
                    <CustomDatePicker
                      format="dd/MM"
                      id="fieldEnd"
                      name="fieldEnd"
                      {...field}
                      onChange={(val) => setFieldValue("fieldEnd", val)}
                    />
                  );
                }}
              </Field>
              <ErrorMessage name="fieldEnd" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default CustomForm;
```

I used the validation step as the trigger point to perform the calculation, but had trouble to back-fill to derived date to the target field. Apart from that, I also faced the following two issues:

- The first date change did not trigger the validation, but the second change seemed to have triggered it correctly
- A warning on console

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://...
```

I knew the solution was not perfect but it was my best attempt after many trial and errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at yup's `.when` condition to ensure validation of your desired date separation?  You can see others have tackled similar issues with it --> [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675561/how-to-make-end-date-at-most-one-day-after-start-date-in-yup-validation)

Comment: Thank you for your reply neonwatty. I will take a look and mark your answer. Cheers!